# Relationship between degree sequence and chromatic number of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ and $H$ be two (finite, simple) connected graphs with the same degree sequence. Is it possible to make $|\chi(G) - \chi(H)|$ arbitrarily large by choosing appropriate $G$ and $H$ ?

Comment: It would improve your Question to add more context.  Have you considered some small examples?  Can you explain what you tried and what difficulty it may lead to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$, and let $H$ consist of two copies of $K_{n/2}$ with a perfect matching between them. (The perfect matching makes $H$ connected and brings its degrees up to the right value.)

Then $G$ and $H$ both have the degree sequence $(n/2, n/2, \dots, n/2)$, but $\chi(G) = 2$ and $\chi(H) = n/2$.

(You can also think of $H$ as the graph product $K_{n/2} \square K_2$.)